# Not able to SSH into VM using any of the authorized IDs even from console

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, ssh-keys

I am not able to SSH into my VM on google cloud. The only thing that has changed is that I have now upgraded my account to a paid account from free account. My billing subscription was expired before I could upgrade my account. The VM is still intact. I can see the files inside using FileZilla tool. Not sure how to run anything on this server anymore.

Comment: 'The VM is still intact' - are you able to login to the GCP console? Can you try ssh via Google Cloud shell? Is this a Win or Linux VM?

Comment: Could you share the specific error you are receiving when you attempt to connect your instance by SSH? 
How long has your billing account been inactive? https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier?hl=en#how-to-upgrade
Could you please check your Serial Logs in order to see if you find some specific error, (Out of Memory, Out of space in your disk, etc.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. When trying to do SSH from console, there are no errors. It keep saying on desplay that its taking longer than usual to transfer SSH keys.
From Google Cloud SDK the error is : "SFATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)" 
This same error I get from even Putty.
The serial log are intact. 
Observations: 
1. OS Login is also not working
2. Created another VM mapping this one, and the new VM also has same issue. 
3. Billing was inactive only for a couple of days.

Comment: Could you check if your OS Login is set as "TRUE" ? if so, could you change to FALSE and try again? Additionally, you could check the if you can try to access through the SSH button in your console, go to [VM instance](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances) and click SSH button, and please update your answer with the error you get. Also you can check the [guest environment](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#wgei), Could you create a completely new instance and try? please let us know the results.